# JSF hiding exceptions?

Tags: java, jsf, jpa

I have a managed bean for a JSF page which is doing JPA calls in the constructor to populate fields in the bean. I'm having a bit of trouble with another call to persist an entity (to populate data for testing). I'm expecting it to throw some sort of exception since it's not working, but I'm not getting anything. Just of the heck of it I tried the following:

```
Query newQuery = em.createQuery("Bad Syntax");
List newList = newQuery.getResultList();
```

I'd expect an `IllegalArgumentException` here since the query string is completely invalid, but the page still loads and I don't see any exceptions anywhere.

Am I right in expecting this exception? If so, why am I not seeing it?

Comment: Have u tried to debug to see what is the value of "newList" after the query is executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it appears there was some sort of issue with NetBeans not redeploying everything properly. I had been running clean builds while I was originally troubleshooting, but after letting things sit for a couple of days and going back to it, I'm now seeing what I'd expect to see.

> > Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
> >     Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [Bad Syntax], line 1, column 0: unexpected token [Bad].

I'm not sure what lesson I've really learned from this, but it's definitely removed some of my trust NetBeans.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't suppress exceptions by default. As a quick test I tried the following:

```
package com.example;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
public class Bean {

    public Bean() {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No!");
    }

}
```

with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>test</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        #{bean}
    </h:body>
</html>
```

and I got a nice default error page with the following trace in the webbrowser:

```
javax.el.ELException: /test.xhtml: Cant instantiate class: com.example.Bean.
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:83)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:75)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:380)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:126)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Cant instantiate class: com.example.Bean.
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:193)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:405)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:86)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:61)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:217)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ELText.java:141)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:78)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No!
    at com.example.Bean.<init>(Bean.java:9)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188)
    ... 36 more
1-jun-2010 13:51:06 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No!
    at com.example.Bean.<init>(Bean.java:9)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:405)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:86)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:61)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:217)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ELText.java:141)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:75)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:380)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:126)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

So your problem probably lies somewhere else. Have you run a debugger?

Comment: I have run a debugger, but I wasn't sure what to look for, so I don't have any useful information at present. One thing I did notice is that it didn't appear to stop on the line which creates the query.

Comment: Is it possible for a line to be skipped if there's no branching anywhere around it? I'll have to post the contents of the bean, I suppose. I'll try to do this tonight.

Comment: BalusC, you were definitely on target with your previous comment. It really seems like the code was completely out of sync between the NetBeans and Glassfish, though I wasn't getting any deployment errors.